# Schema Definition For Audit-like Asset Tracking (Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, database-design, entity-framework-5

I'm having trouble designing the relationships between entities in my schema. The issue is that each `Asset` (projector,laptop,etc...) can have a change in purpose/location (among other things), and if I wanted to get the *most recent* of these values which it would currently involve copious joining etc.... To keep track of these changes I have defined a schema like so:

[image]

Meaning that an `AssetInstance` represents a use of the `Asset`, i.e being loaned out, sent to repair. Each `AssetInstance` is responsible for recording the location,shelf (if applicable) and purpose of the `Asset`. However if I use this approach and I want to get the current user of an `Asset` with `AssetID = 1`, I would need to join Asset,AssetInstance then sort by *Date* and select the top one, then join that with `User` to get their name.

Ideally I would like Asset to keep retain the most recent Purpose,Location,Shelf and User it had associated with it. I realize this could be accomplished by adding these relationships to Asset and then in my code after a new AssetInstance is created for an Asset update the Assets columns appropriately.

To me this seems far from ideal and I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could see the design from another viewpoint
Lets say `AssetInstance` `is a` reallocation of shelf,location and purpose.So I prefer calling the table `Transaction` or `Relocation-Transaction`. 
As shelf,location and purpose are naturally properties of `Asset` we will have relation of them in asset Table. **Last location, shelf and purpose** are saved in these foreign keys in asset table.
relocation-transaction table contains the history of relocation, so we will insert a row in that when the asset is re-locating(*perhaps even in first place of asset creation*).
I think it would be a good idea to have a base table for transactions, may further actions on the asset will be needed to have traced and reported, like asset out of ordering, selling ... 
A draft model would be something like this:
 
[image]
Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 This is a way of doing it I hadn't thought of though I'd rather have the purpose,shelf and location be stored in Asset (exactly like you've done) and then just keep all transactions in 'AssetInstance'. Simply because people are likely to be searching the database and having one AssetInstance table simplifies this.